# How to get value out of complex json with a hyperlink C#

Tags: json

My JSON is:

```
{
    "kind": "tm:ltm:pool:poolstats",
    "generation": 198990,
    "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~part~pool-1/stats?ver=12.1.2",
    "entries": {
        "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~part~pool-1/~part~pool-1/stats": {
            "nestedStats": {
                "kind": "tm:ltm:pool:poolstats",
                "selfLink": "https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~part~pool-1/~part~pool-1/stats?ver=12.1.2",
                "entries": {
                    "activeMemberCnt": {
                        "value": 2
                    },
                    "connqAll.ageEdm": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connqAll.ageEma": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connqAll.ageHead": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connqAll.ageMax": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connqAll.depth": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connqAll.serviced": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connq.ageEdm": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connq.ageEma": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connq.ageHead": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connq.ageMax": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connq.depth": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "connq.serviced": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "curSessions": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "minActiveMembers": {
                        "value": 0
                    },
                    "monitorRule": {
                        "description": "/Common/tcp"
                    },
                    "tmName": {
                        "description": "/part/pool-1"
                    },
                    "serverside.bitsIn": {
                        "value": 517432
                    },
                    "serverside.bitsOut": {
                        "value": 4378224
                    },
                    "**serverside.curConns**": {
                        "**value**": 0
                    },
                    "serverside.maxConns": {
                        "value": 16
                    },
                    "serverside.pktsIn": {
                        "value": 697
                    },
                    "serverside.pktsOut": {
                        "value": 697
                    },
                    "serverside.totConns": {
                        "value": 144
                    },
                    "status.availabilityState": {
                        "description": "available"
                    },
                    "status.enabledState": {
                        "description": "enabled"
                    },
                    "status.statusReason": {
                        "description": "The pool is available"
                    },
                    "totRequests": {
                        "value": 55
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get value of "serverside.curConns"'s "value" key. How?

Comment: We need more. What have you tried so far? What language are you attempting this in?

Comment: I have tried accessing it using SelectToken(). I am using NewtonSoft.json within my C# project.

Comment: Please show the code you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much more about your use case, here's an example of how you can access the requested token via its direct path using JSON.NET C#:

Runnable DotNetFiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/yecPbV

The meat of the logic is pasted below for convenience:

```
var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var serverSideConnections = jsonObject.SelectToken("entries['https://localhost/mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~part~pool-1/~part~pool-1/stats'].nestedStats.entries['serverside.curConns'].value");

Console.WriteLine("Current Connections: " + serverSideConnections.Value<int>());
```

Where `json` above is a string representation of your json blob.